# problemas con variables de sesion perl

Tags: perl

Tengo el siguiente código y no comprendo por qué no me guarda los datos de las filas luego de ejecutar la consulta.

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" 
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);

use CGI;
use CGI::Session(); #Módulo para la sesión
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); #Muestra posibles errores en el navegador
use DBI; #Conector para la base de datos
use CGI::Session;
$session = CGI::Session->new();
$CGISESSID = $session->id();
#Se crea el objeto CGI
my $cgi = new CGI;

### Recibimos la clave y el valor de los parámetros

my $email = $cgi->param("Email", $cgi->param("Email"));
my $email2 = $cgi->param("Email2", $cgi->param("Email2"));


### Datos de conexión a la base de datos

my $admin = "root";
my $pass = "";
my $base_de_datos = "amaclone";
my $servidor = "localhost";

### Se establece la conexión a la base de datos mysql

my $mysql = DBI -> connect("DBI:mysql:$base_de_datos;host=$servidor", $admin, $pass) || die "Error al conectar con la base de datos: $DBI::errstr";

### Preparamos la consulta para seleccionar datos

my $consulta = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' AND password='$email2'") || die "Error al seleccionar datos: $DBI::errstr";

#Se ejecuta la consulta

$consulta->execute();

### Se busca si existe la fila con tal usuario y password

my $encontrar = 0;
while ($consulta->fetch())
{
    $encontrar = 1;
}

### Si la fila existe

if ($encontrar == 1)
{
    print $cgi->header(-type=> 'text/html', -charset=>'utf-8');
    $datos=$consulta->fetchrow_arrayref();
    print "Bienvenido usuario $email,sus datos son correctos";
    print "Código:$datos->[0] Nombre :$datos->[1]\n";
}
else
{
    print $cgi->header(-type=> 'text/html', -charset=>'utf-8');
    print "sus datos son incorrectos";
    print "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El método fetch() es un alias del método fetchrow_arrayref().

Lo que está pasando es que el while() que usas para establecer la variable $encontrar a 1, agota toda la respuesta a la consulta, por lo que después, cuando quieres hacer otro fetchrow_arrayref(), ya no devuelve nada.

Lo que tienes que hacer es almacenar el resultado en el primer while(). Por ejemplo, sería algo así (no probado):

```
my $datos_ref;          # referencia a array de arrays

while (my $row_ref = $consulta->fetch()) {
    push @{$datos_ref},  $row_ref;
}
```

Y ya tienes en $datos_ref la matriz de resultados. Solo tienes que cambiar el if() por

```
if (@$datos_ref) {          # sí hay resultados
```

Pero, recuerda, que es una matriz, no una fila. Deberás recorrer los array del primer nivel, y cada uno de ellos será otro (referencia a) array.

```
for my $row_ref (@$datos_ref) {
    print "Código:$row_ref->[0] Nombre :$row_ref->[1]\n";
}
```

Comment: luego lo probare y te dire si funcionó de antemano gracias

Comment: En el foro de Perl en Español encontrarás más ejemplos.

Comment: oye una pregunta ... como puedo guardar cada dato en una variable de sesión? y como puedo ocupar esas variables

Comment: Con el método param(). Mira el ejemplo en la página de manual de CGI::Session https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#SYNOPSIS

Comment: ahora me da problemas para cargar las variables de sesion en otro script CGI

Comment: Es posible que la sesión haya expirado. ¿Qué tiempo de expiración está usando? Por favor, repase los pasos necesarios en CGI::Session::Tutorial https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Tutorial#PROGRAMMING-STYLE

Comment: no le puse lo de expirar... en serio me gustaria su ayuda personalmente ya que estoy desarrollando un proyecto

Comment: Si no se le indica tiempo de expiración, la sesión caduca cuando se cierra el navegador web: http://perlenespanol.com/foro/problema-al-cerrar-sesion-cgi-session-t7723.html#p33146

Comment: en mi caso no es así :/ subire otra pregunta con ambos código para que pueda verlo